# RabbitVCS does not work because of python error

Tags: python, opensuse

Hello
I cannot start running rabbitvcs on openSUSE 11.3 64bit.
I tried to run test.py file which is located in rabbitvcs folder.
It returns the following errors:

```
jenea@linux-nguv:/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rabbitvcs> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    import lib.helper
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/rabbitvcs/lib/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rabbitvcs.lib.log import Log
ImportError: No module named lib.log
```

PS: I know that is not quite programming question but it seems to me that error occurs because of some paths or settings.

Unfortunately I've no idea where to dig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although stupid the answer is the following:

There were two folders where rabbitvcs was intalled. The first was in /usr/lib/rabbitvcs and the second was in /usr/lib64/rabbitvcs. I'm not sure why there was described issue but after I deleted rabbitvcs folder in /usr/lib64 it started to work normally.